# Sinatra and ActiveRecord (no Rails) - Creating test database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sinatra, sinatra-activerecord

I'm trying out a simpler setup for using Sinatra with ActiveRecord and I am running into some puzzling problems and would love another set of eyes on it. I will give all the relevant files:

database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3

test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

Rakefile:

```
require_relative "demo_app"
require 'sinatra/activerecord/rake'
require 'rake/testtask'

Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  t.pattern = "test/*_test.rb"
end
```

test_helper.rb:

```
ENV['RACK_ENV'] = 'test'
ENV["SINATRA_ENV"] = "test"

require_relative '../demo_app'
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'rack/test'

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!
```

Migration file:

```
class CreatePeople < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :people do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.date :dob
      t.string :gender
      t.string :gender
      t.integer :zipcode
    end
  end
end
```

Now, I want to run tests against the test database. When I try to do

`rake db:create RAILS_ENV=test` - it creates a development.sqlite3

`rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test` - same + runs migration

I know that I am using ActiveRecord outside of Rails so I suspect the problem lies somewhere relating to the processing of database.yml or some environment variable or something. But I can't figure it out.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try `RACK_ENV` instead of `RAILS_ENV`:

```
$ rake db:create RACK_ENV=test
```

Or:

```
$ RACK_ENV=test rake db:create
```

Comment: Interesting: creates an empty test.sqlite3 (0 bytes)

Comment: Okay, what does `db:migrate` do?

Comment: Ah: RACK_ENV=test rake db:migrate seems to work, and so does RACK_ENV=test rake db:seed. They are creating the test db. Can you explain the relationship between rails_env and rack_env?

Comment: [Rack](http://rack.github.io/) is the web server interface that Sinatra uses (Rails also uses it, incidentally). `RACK_ENV` serves the same purpose as `RAILS_ENV` in Sinatra.

Comment: `RACK_ENV` does not serve the same purpose as `RAILS_ENV`. https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/ab172af1b63f0d8e91ce579dd2907c43b96cf82a/lib/rack/server.rb#L157

Comment: Woow, I was looking for it soo long time! Why they didn't put this in docs?! Or maybe I missed it?